# Why use ん here?

Tags: grammar, て-form

車は駐車場から出てきていったん止まりました. why use ん here? why dont' use ~ 出てきていって止まりました.

Comment: Spoiler: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%93

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing a verb which does not really exist there.

[一旦【いったん】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/13469/m0u/) is an adverb which means "once", "temporarily", or "for a moment".